# How to count only the first occurrence group by users

Tags: mysql

I'm having the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `client_notes` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`note` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`datepost` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Here I store notes inserted by users for clients. 
Every `client_id` have some notes, added by `user_id`. The target is to count how many times the broker add the first note (extra option could be a period for this week for example in `where` clause)

```
+----+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | broker_id| client | datepost           |
+----+---------+------------------------------+
|  1 |    1     |   10   | 29-11-2017 10:00:00| <- this is first note for this client
|  2 |    2     |   10   | 29-11-2017 10:20:00|
|  3 |    2     |   15   | 28-11-2017 10:10:00| <- this is first note for this client
|  4 |    1     |   15   | 28-11-2017 10:20:00|
|  5 |    1     |   15   | 28-11-2017 10:30:00|
+----+----------+--------+--------------------+
```

The output should be:

```
+-----------+-------+
| broker_id | count |
+-----------+-------+
|     1     |   1   |
|     2     |   1   |
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: What have you tried already? SO is not to get your homework done freely w/o spending time yourself!

Comment: `SELECT broker_id, COUNT(*) FROM client_notes group by broker_id 
   HAVING min(datepost)` - this is what I tried but it doesn't show correct information.

Comment: `The target is to count how many times the broker add the first note` - Shouldn't this always either be 1 or 0?

Comment: The example upper is showing what's the end point of query. Of course only one broker(user) could add first note to some client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use the unnecessary and nonstandard quotes on simple SQL identifiers:

```
CREATE TABLE client_notes (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    note text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    datepost datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

To get the "first" anything implies an order and a minimum.  You want the smallest date for each client:

```
-- Note: example data column names don't match above table definition
select min(datepost) as datepost, client_id from ENGINE group by client_id
```

The result of any SELECT is itelf a table, and can be operated on,

```
select broker_id, count(*) as 'count'
from ENGINE as E
join (
    select min(datepost) as datepost, client_id from ENGINE group by client_id
) as A
on E.client_id = A.client_id
and E.datepost = A.datepost
group by broker_id
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need and the result is accurate